# How insert time_t into PostgreSQL timestamp field

Tags: c++, c, postgresql, timestamp

How to insert time/date received into time_t structure into column which has 'timestamp without timezone' type?

Previously I was using int8 as data type and time_t perfectly fits but I would like to know how to do it with timestamp field(preferably without casting time_t to string from caller program) using PQexecParams call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [to_timestamp](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) function.
Example:

```
 select to_timestamp(1000000000)::timestamp;
```

Result:

```
   to_timestamp     
---------------------  
 2001-09-09 03:46:40
1 row)
```

Comment: Note that the cast to `timestamp` is necessary because `to_timestamp()` returns a `timestamp with time zone` whereas the question specifies `timestamp without time zone` (of which `timestamp` is the short name). (EDITED to avoid referring to deleted comment)

Comment: Thanks for answer but looking for solution how to insert time_t using PQexecParams call

Comment: So make the query `INSERT INTO... VALUES(to_timestamp($1),...)` and pass it to PQexecParams()